# Можно ли поменять шрифт в ttk, если уже стоит тема?

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

Вот пример кода - при запуске шрифт не меняется, если убрать тему - то работает.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from ttkthemes import ThemedStyle
from tkinter import ttk
root = tk.Tk()
s = ttk.Style()
s.configure('my.TButton', font=('TF2 Build', 12))
b = ttk.Button(root, text='Press me', style='my.TButton').pack()
style = ThemedStyle(root)
style.set_theme("clam")
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Короткий ответ:  к сожалению нет нельзя. Сам долгo пытался что-то такое сделать, но наверно единственный вариант — это каким-то образом отредактировать саму тему.

Comment: Ладно, обойдусь без пользовательских шрифтов)